# $Pre and the attribute HoldAll

Tags: programming

Please, consider

```
$Pre = If[go, #, Null] &;
```

Now, this

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 1;
go = TrueQ @ (b != 0);
a/b
```

returns `1`, and this

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 0;
go = TrueQ @ (b != 0);
a/b
```

throws a `Power::infy` message. The reason is that: *Unless* `$Pre` *is assigned to be a function which holds its arguments unevaluated, input expressions will be evaluated before* `$Pre` *is applied* (from Documentation Center)

Let's consider, instead

```
    $Pre = If[go, #, Null] &;
    go = True;
    SetAttributes[$Pre, HoldAll];
```

This still give `1`

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 1;
go = TrueQ @ (b != 0);
a/b
```

but this

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 0;
go = TrueQ @ (b != 0);
a/b
```

should give `Null`. On the contrary, the error message appears again. Can you, please, explain why ?

## addendum

With

```
$Pre = Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll];
```

by

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 1;
go = TrueQ@(b != 0);
a/b
```

I get

```
If[go,go=True;,Null]
If[go,a=1;,Null]
If[go,b=1;,Null]
If[go,go=TrueQ[b!=0];,Null]
If[go,a/b,Null]
```

and

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 0;
go = TrueQ@(b != 0);
a/b
```

returns

```
If[go,go=True;,Null]
If[go,a=1;,Null]
If[go,b=0;,Null]
If[go,go=TrueQ[b!=0];,Null]
If[go,a/b,Null]
```

Comment: The *value of* `$Pre` should be a function with attribute `HoldAll`; in your case, you could try `$Pre = Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll]`. I haven't tested it yet though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all start a new kernel. The following evaluates without a problem:

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 1;
go = TrueQ@(b != 0);
```

So far so good, i.e. `go == True`. Now

```
$Pre = Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll];
a/b
```

evaluates to `1` which is correct. Now restart the kernel again, and type

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 0;
go = TrueQ@(b != 0);
```

Again everything is working, i.e. `go == False`. Now evaluate

```
$Pre = Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll];
a/b
```

and you will get `Null`. Again, this is the correct response. However you are doing something quite differently. You start by assigning a value to `$Pre` like this:

```
$Pre = Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll];
```

and then you do this:

```
go = True;
a = 1;
b = 1;
go = TrueQ@(b != 0);
a/b
```

and it's not working, because the function you assigned to `$Pre` is preventing the assignment of a value to `go`, and any subsequent assignment, from happening.

```
Function[{arg}, If[go, arg, Null], HoldAll][go = True]
-> (arguments are held) Function[{arg}, If[go, go = True, Null]]
-> If[go, go = True, Null] (cannot be evaluated, no assignment is happening)
```

`If[go, ...]` does not evaluate because `go` is neither true nor false.

What is happening in your first example, `$Pre = If[go, #, Null] &;`, is slightly different. Again reset your kernel and run the following:

```
$Pre = If[go, #, Null] &;
go = True;
```

What happened here? *Mathematica* did something like this:

```
If[go, #, Null]&[go = True] 
-> (the argument is not held) If[go, #, Null]&[True]
```

when the argument was evaluated, `go` was assigned a value as a side effect because the argument is not held. This actually solves the problem with the previous approach, but it has the new problem that you noticed: because arguments are not held, `a/b` is evaluated. The flow is like this:

```
If[go, #, Null]&[a/b]
-> If[go, #, Null]&[ComplexInfinity]
-> If[go, ComplexInfinity, Null]
-> Null
```

So the result is right, but because `a/b` was evaluated it will still print the error message. You can avoid the error message by typing `Quiet[a/b]`.